# Why is the computational complexity O(n^4)?

Tags: java, big-o

```java
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < i * i; j++) {
        if(j % i == 0) {
            for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how when j = i, 2i, 3i... the last `for` loop runs n times. I guess I just don't understand how we came to that conclusion based on the `if` statement.

Edit: I know how to compute the complexity for all the loops except for why  the last loop executes i times based on the mod operator... I just don't see how it's i. Basically, why can't j % i go up to i * i rather than i?

Comment: hey its calculated exponentially like for first 2 it will be n  2 and *2
2*2=4

Comment: You can reduce the complexity of this code by multiple **large** factors. **Hint**: The sum of numbers 1 to n is ((n+1)*n)/2 **Hint 2**: `for (j = i; j < i *i; j += i)` then you don't need the modulus test (because `j` is guaranteed to be divisible by `i`).

Comment: O() function is a ball-park function so any loop  in this example is adding to complexity. The second loop is running up to n^2. if-statements are ignored.

Comment: @ChristophBauer `if` statements are **absolutely not** ignored. This `if` statement means the complexity is O(n^4) instead of O(n^5), because it causes the innermost loop to only execute `i` times instead of `i*i` times for each iteration of the second loop.

Comment: Hint3:  If we treat this as a function `sum(n)` then the value returned by `sum(n)` will have the same complexity as the cost for computing `sum(n)`.  So if you can work out an algebraic formula for `sum(n)`, that will give you the computational complexity.

Comment: @kaya3 totally missed the `k < n^2` part.So it is O(n^5) but knowledge (by understanding the `if`) suggests O(n^4).

Comment: Along the lines of @ElliottFrisch 's comment, the loop over `j` could equivalently be rewritten with a new variable `jprime` as `for(jprime=1; jprime<i; jprime++)` with the `if` statement being replaced by the substitution `j = jprime*i`, which perhaps makes explicit that only `i` many values of `j` will be considered for the innermost loop.

Comment: If this isn't just a class exercise, change the second loop to for(int j = i; j < i * i; j+=i)

Comment: j % i, or j mod i, can only go up to i (actually, i-1) because the modulus of one number by a second number, call it in general "b", is always and only in the range 0...b-1, inclusive. This is, in effect, part of the definition of "modulo".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Indeed. If you continue with this logic, you can refactor the 4 loops to just `(n - 1) * n * (n - 2) * (3 * n - 1) / 24`.

Answer (score 53):

Let's label the loops A, B and C:

```java
int sum = 0;
// loop A
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    // loop B
    for(int j = 1; j < i * i; j++) {
        if(j % i == 0) {
            // loop C
            for(int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Loop A iterates O(*n*) times.
- Loop B iterates O(*i*<sup>2</sup>) times **per iteration of A**. For each of these iterations:

  - `j % i == 0` is evaluated, which takes O(1) time.
  - On 1/*i* of these iterations, loop C iterates *j* times, doing O(1) work per iteration. Since *j* is O(*i*<sup>2</sup>) on average, and this is only done for 1/*i* iterations of loop B, the average cost is O(*i*<sup>2</sup> / *i*) = O(*i*).

Multiplying all of this together, we get O(*n* × *i*<sup>2</sup> × (1 + *i*)) = O(*n* × *i*<sup>3</sup>). Since *i* is on average O(*n*), this is O(*n*<sup>4</sup>).

---

The tricky part of this is saying that the `if` condition is only true 1/*i* of the time:

> Basically, why can't j % i go up to i * i rather than i?

In fact, `j` does go up to `j < i * i`, not just up to `j < i`. But the condition `j % i == 0` is true if and only if `j` is a multiple of `i`.

The multiples of `i` within the range are `i`, `2*i`, `3*i`, ..., `(i-1) * i`. There are `i - 1` of these, so loop C is reached `i - 1` times despite loop B iterating `i * i - 1` times.

Comment: In O(n × i^2 × (1 + i)) why 1+i ?

Comment: Because the `if` condition takes O(1) time on every iteration of loop B. It's dominated by loop C here, but I counted it above so it's just "showing my working".

Answer (score 15):

- The first loop consumes `n` iterations.
- The second loop consumes `n*n` iterations. Imagine the case when `i=n`, then `j=n*n`.
- The third loop consumes `n` iterations because it's executed only `i` times, where `i` is bounded to `n` in the worst case.

Thus, the code complexity is O(n×n×n×n).

I hope this helps you understand.

Answer (score 5):

All the other answers are correct, I just want to amend the following.
I wanted to see, if the reduction of executions of the inner k-loop was sufficient to reduce the actual complexity below `O(n⁴).` So I wrote the following:

```java
for (int n = 1; n < 363; ++n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        for(int j = 1; j < i * i; ++j) {
            if(j % i == 0) {
                for(int k = 0; k < j; ++k) {
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    long cubic = (long) Math.pow(n, 3);
    long hypCubic = (long) Math.pow(n, 4);
    double relative = (double) (sum / (double) hypCubic);
    System.out.println("n = " + n + ": iterations = " + sum +
            ", n³ = " + cubic + ", n⁴ = " + hypCubic + ", rel = " + relative);
}
```

After executing this, it becomes obvious, that the complexity is in fact `n⁴`. The last lines of output look like this:

```
n = 356: iterations = 1989000035, n³ = 45118016, n⁴ = 16062013696, rel = 0.12383254507467704
n = 357: iterations = 2011495675, n³ = 45499293, n⁴ = 16243247601, rel = 0.12383580700180696
n = 358: iterations = 2034181597, n³ = 45882712, n⁴ = 16426010896, rel = 0.12383905075183874
n = 359: iterations = 2057058871, n³ = 46268279, n⁴ = 16610312161, rel = 0.12384227647628734
n = 360: iterations = 2080128570, n³ = 46656000, n⁴ = 16796160000, rel = 0.12384548432498857
n = 361: iterations = 2103391770, n³ = 47045881, n⁴ = 16983563041, rel = 0.12384867444612208
n = 362: iterations = 2126849550, n³ = 47437928, n⁴ = 17172529936, rel = 0.1238518469862343
```

What this shows is, that the actual relative difference between actual `n⁴` and the complexity of this code segment is a factor asymptotic towards a value around `0.124...` (actually 0.125). While it does not give us the exact value, we can deduce, the following:

Time complexity is `n⁴/8 ~ f(n)` where `f` is your function/method.

- The wikipedia-page on Big O notation states in the tables of 'Family of Bachmann–Landau notations' that the `~` defines the limit of the two operand sides is equal. Or:

  > f is equal to g asymptotically

(I chose 363 as excluded upper bound, because `n = 362` is the last value for which we get a sensible result. After that, we exceed the long-space and the relative value becomes negative.)

User kaya3 figured out the following:

> The asymptotic constant is exactly 1/8 = 0.125, by the way; [here's the exact formula via Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+for+i+%3D+1+to+n-1+of+i+*+i+*+%28i-1%29+%2F+2).

Comment: Of course, O(n⁴) * 0.125 = O(n⁴). Multiplying the runtime by a positive constant factor doesn't change the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: This is true. However I was trying to reflect the actual complexity, not the upperbound estimate. As I found no other syntax for expressing time complexity other than O-notation, i fell back on that. It is however not a 100% sensible to write it like this.

Comment: You can use [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) to say the time complexity is `n⁴/8 + o(n⁴)`, but it's possible to give a stricter expression `n⁴/8 + O(n³)` with big O anyway.

Comment: @TreffnonX big OH is a mathematical solid concept. So what you're doing is fundementally wrong/meaningless. Of course you're free to redefine mathematical concepts, but that's a big can of worms you're opening then. The way to define it in a stricter context is what kaya3 described, you go an order "lower" and define it that way. (Though in mathematics you typically use the reciprocate).

Comment: You are correct. I corrected myself again. This time, I use the asymtotic growth towards the same limit, as defined in the Family of Bachmann-Landau notations on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation . I hope this is now mathematically correct enough to not incite revolt ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Remove `if` and modulo without changing the complexity

Here's the original method:

```
public static long f(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < i * i; j++) {
            if (j % i == 0) {
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    sum++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you're confused by the `if` and modulo, you can just refactor them away, with `j` jumping directly from `i` to `2*i` to `3*i` ... :

```
public static long f2(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < i * i; j = j + i) {
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To make it even easier to calculate the complexity, you can introduce an intermediary  `j2` variable, so that every loop variable is incremented by 1 at each iteration:

```
public static long f3(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j2 = 1; j2 < i; j2++) {
            int j = j2 * i;
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You can use debugging or old-school `System.out.println` in order to check that `i, j, k` triplet is always the same in each method.

## Closed form expression

As mentioned by others, you can use the fact that the sum of the first `n`  integers is equal to `n * (n+1) / 2` (see [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)). If you use this simplification for every loop, you get :

```
public static long f4(int n) {
    return (n - 1) * n * (n - 2) * (3 * n - 1) / 24;
}
```

It is obviously *not* the same complexity as the original code but it does return the same values.

If you google the first terms, you can notice that `0 0 0 2 11 35 85 175 322 546 870 1320 1925 2717 3731` appear in ["Stirling numbers of the first kind: s(n+2, n)."](https://oeis.org/A000914), with two `0`s added at the beginning. It means that `sum` is the [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) `s(n, n-2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the first two loops.

The first one is simple, it's looping from 1 to n. The second one is more interesting. It goes from 1 to i squared. Let's see some examples:

```
e.g. n = 4    
i = 1  
j loops from 1 to 1^2  
i = 2  
j loops from 1 to 2^2  
i = 3  
j loops from 1 to 3^2
```

In total, the `i and j loops` combined have `1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2`.
There is a formula for the sum of first n squares, `n * (n+1) * (2n + 1) / 6`, which is roughly `O(n^3)`.

You have one last `k loop` which loops from 0 to `j` if and only if `j % i == 0`. Since `j` goes from 1 to `i^2`, `j % i == 0` is true for `i` times. Since the `i loop` iterates over `n`, you have one extra `O(n)`.

So you have `O(n^3)` from `i and j loops` and another `O(n)` from `k loop` for a grand total of `O(n^4)`

Comment: I know how to compute the complexity for all the loops except for why  the last loop executes i times based on the mod operator... I just don't see how it's i. Basically, why can't j % i go up to i * i rather than i?

Comment: @user11452926 let's say the i was 5. j would go from 1 to 25 in the 2nd loop. However, `j % i == 0` only when j is 5, 10, 15, 20 and 25. 5 times, like the value of i. If you would write down the numbers from to 1 to 25 in 5 x 5 square, only the 5th column would contain the numbers divisible by 5. This works for any number of i. Draw a square of n by n using the numbers 1 to n^2. The nth column will contain the numbers divisible by n. You have n rows, so n numbers from 1 to n^2 divisible by n.

Comment: Thanks! makes sense! What if it was an arbitrary number like 24 rather than 25, will the square trick still work?

Comment: 25 comes when `i` hits 5, so the `j` loops from 1 to 25, you can't choose an arbitrary number. If your 2nd loop would go to a fixed number, e.g. 24, instead of `i * i`, that would be a constant number and wouldn't be tied to `n`, so it would be `O(1)`. If you're thinking about `j < i * i` vs. `j <= i * i`, that will not matter much, as there will be `n` and `n-1` operations, but in the Big-oh notation, both means `O(n)`